# How to use GML files in Lemon?

Tags: graph, lemon-graph-library, graph-modelling-language

I have a lot of topologies in GML format and want to process them with Lemon (http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon), but it doesn't support GML files. Is there a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a solution called GML2LGF converter. It's a standalone app, which you can convert your gml files into Lemon Graph Format.

http://csikor.tmit.bme.hu/GML2LGF/

Cheers.

Comment: Project has moved to [https://github.com/cslev/gml2lgf](https://github.com/cslev/gml2lgf)